# WSO2 Custom Throttle Policy For Each End-User IP Address In X-Forwarded-For

Tags: wso2, throttling, api-gateway, rate-limiting

I use WSO2 API Managet 2.6.0 as the API Gateway in front of my Spring Boot REST APIs.

I would like to add a Custom Throttle Policy to set the rate limit per the end-user ip address, which is put in the request header `X-Forwarded-For` by the internet-facing WAF.

WSO2 document shows some example of custom policy written in Siddhi language but it doesn't have enough example.

The most detailed artitcle I can find is https://dzone.com/articles/implement-user-based-throttling-with-wso2-api-mana, which shows an example of rate limiting by userId.

```
FROM RequestStream
SELECT userId, userId as throttleKey
INSERT INTO EligibilityStream;
​
FROM EligibilityStream#throttler:timeBatch(1 min)
SELECT throttleKey, (count(userId) &gt;= 5) as isThrottled, expiryTimeStamp group by throttleKey
INSERT ALL EVENTS into ResultStream;
```

The above Siddhi query tells WSO2 to extract `userId` from the request and use it as the throttleKey and limit each throttleKey be less than 5 transactions per 1 minutes.

I would like to know how to modify this Siddhi query to use the ip address in request header `X-Forwarded-For` instead of `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a throttling policy for a specific header or specific IP you can use advanced throttling policy configurations (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+New+Throttling+Policies).

Comment: thanks but the advanced policy only allow me to do rate limit on   specific values of ip. In this case I want that the rate limit is applied to each incoming user ip

Comment: I mean In your case adding a header condition isn't sufficient?

Comment: The header condition also requires me to enter Header Name and Param Value. But I don't want to limit a specific Param Value, instead I would like the rate limit to apply per each incoming Param Value dynamically

Comment: You can use a regex like (.*?) to match all params.  For that you need to enable `<EnableHeaderConditions>true</EnableHeaderConditions>` in <APIM-HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml

Comment: Let's discuss this with an example. if I set the rule of 1000 requests per minute with the header condition such as `Header Name: X-Forwarded-For, Param Value: .*?` it would mean that the rule will **share** for any requests with header `X-Forwared-For=<anything>`, which mean that if I have different 2000 users using my application at the same time, half of them would get the quota exceed error, right? Instead, I would like the rule that can block each individual user in case he/she is a hacker and attacks my APIs with more than 1000 requests per minutes, while others can still use the app.